# xcode, analyse error on alloc

Tags: objective-c, ipad, xcode4

I got error message, but not sure how to get rid of it.

```
-- Method returns an Objective-C object with a +1 retain count (owning reference)
```

and

```
--Object allocated on line 46 is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1 (object leaked)
```

for line aAA and bBB

```
+ ( CustConf* ) initEmptyCustConf { 
    CustConf* theObject = [[CustConf alloc] init];
    theObject.ID = 0;
    theObject.aAA= [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@""];
    theObject.Number_Ndx = 0;
    theObject.bBB = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@""];

    return [theObject autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@""];` is unnecessary.  Just use `@""`.

Change your `initEmptyCustConf` to this:

```
+ (CustConf *) initEmptyCustConf { 
    CustConf *theObject = [[CustConf alloc] init];
    theObject.ID = 0;
    theObject.aAA = @"";
    theObject.Number_Ndx = 0;
    theObject.bBB = @"";
    return [theObject autorelease];
}
```

Comment: ok, but why?(sorry if this was basic)
Are object coming from [CustConf alloc] init automatically have a retaincount to 1?

Comment: I'm not sure, can you show the code for the CustConf.m file?  Then I could see, but just allocating should give you a 1 retain count, then autoreleasing (which is the correct thing to do) will -1 sometime in the future.  So that is all correct.  It must be something in the `alloc` or `init` methods of the `CustConf` class.

Comment: Question more about the theObject.aAA = @"" versus theObject.aAA =[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@""]

Even if I need to set a value, no need to alloc it? [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"My int value"];

Comment: Correct, since it's a property the `CustConf` class already retains it and so passing it an allocated string will cause a leak.

Comment: Anytime @Franck!  Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you've defined retained properties for the CustConf class. Since theObject will automatically retain the strings aAA and bBB, and you have not released them in code before the method ends, you will end up leaking memory.

```
+ ( CustConf* ) initEmptyCustConf { 
    CustConf* theObject = [[CustConf alloc] init];
    theObject.ID = 0;
    theObject.aAA= [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@""]; //potential leak
    theObject.Number_Ndx = 0;
    theObject.bBB = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@""]; //potential leak

    return [theObject autorelease];
}
```

To fix this, you need to explicitly release the strings assigned to theObject.aAA and theObject.bBB through release/autorelease, or just use string constants.

```
+ ( CustConf* ) initEmptyCustConf { 

   CustConf* theObject = [[CustConf alloc] init];
    theObject.ID = 0;
    theObject.aAA= @"";
    theObject.Number_Ndx = 0;
    theObject.bBB = @"";

    return [theObject autorelease];
}
```

Also, if your method starts with "init", it is custom to return a retained object, so either  remove the autorelease at the end, or change the method name to reflect the nature of your method.

Comment: `init` does not return a retained object, `alloc`, `copy` and `new` do.

Comment: Actually the analyzer should complain about this. Try it out.

Comment: Came back clean. I agree that the method name isn't good and shouldn't be used, but init does not return a retained object, it returns `self`, a substitute for `self` or `nil`. If `init` returned a retained object `[[NSObject alloc] init]` would be +2